# VS2015 coding on a program, while also updating one of its dll's updates are not seen

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015

I usually did not create .dll files but used class files inside my C# projects. However overtime I kept repeating using the same blocks of code often over and over. So I just wrote those functions into a dll, so far fine.

But with each new project, my collection of regular used methods gets a few updates too. I currently have 2 instances of VS2015 open, so I can work on a my new program, and also update the dll.

However the updates are not always updated, i notice.
So far I simply removed reference, and re-added it to get it updated.
This is not really handy to get intelicense and compiling to work

Maybe there is some future that i don't know of, on how to sync my prj and dll ?. Or a way to have them both open inside one visual studio (opening 2 solutions?)

Comment: A solution can contain more than one project, no point in running VS twice.  Use File > Add > Existing Project.

Comment: I didnt knew that, if you post an asnwer like that i'll vote for you as answer